# Check self-signed certificate (SSL, C#)

Tags: c#, ssl, https

In my desktop application i use HTTPS connection. Certificate is SELF-signed. 
How I can **check** self-signed certificate in c# programatically?

i make i a callback "ValidateRemoteCertificate":

```
 ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateRemoteCertificate)
```

By default, my "ValidateRemoteCertificate" method always return TRUE.
But I think i need to check valid or invalid this certificate. 
How to check it? What i must to check in "ValidateRemoteCertificate"?

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have implemented the callback you know the signature of the callback delegate

```
public delegate bool RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(
    Object sender,
    X509Certificate certificate,
    X509Chain chain,
    SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
```

If I understand you correctly, the client does not have the certificate installed in his store, correct? Although I´d recommend getting your infrastructure in order and deploy a valid certificate, what you could do in your case, is to compare the hash/fingerprint for the certificate to values stored in your application to verify the validty of the certificate.