# Manually trust SSL certificate in C#

Tags: c#, ssl

I am developing an application in C# that will communicate with a server over HTTP and SSL. Is there some way that I can have the program trust the certificate supplied by the server? This certificate would be distributed together with the software, so that it can identify the server without involving an external CA.

Clarification: I want my client application to trust a single certificate that has been hard-coded in the client so that it will only ever trust my own server.

Comment: do you want to trust every certificate (bypass the validation of the certificate aka using not fully signed certificate of your own CA) or some specific ones?

Comment: This question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485313/check-self-signed-certificate-ssl-c - should help you get started?

Comment: @J.Steen that's what I've thought and added my comment - maybe he want's to validate specific ones ..

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair Which the callback would allow, where he could apply his own logic as needed. =)

Comment: Yes, I would like my application to trust a specific certificate that I have created and installed on my server. I have read the question and answer linked, but I am uncertain as to how exactly I should verify it. Could someone kindly provide an example?

I have to admit I find the SSL structure with certificates a bit complicated, and I would like to learn more about all the inner workings. I am used to dealing with SSH where I simply have to verify the public key.

Comment: You could check the thumbprint of the incoming certificate, for instance, along with the name.

Comment: How do I get this thumbprint in C#? If this a safe method of authentication?

Comment: It's reasonably safe (provided you use sha256) though the thumbprint would have to be hardcoded. Which means that when you update the certificate you also need to update the client.

Answer (score 1):

You can use BouncyCastle.

1. Load your CA certificate into BC usign `DotNetUtilities` class using the `FromX509Certificate(X509Certificate)` function
2. Load the public key from the server certificate into BC.
3. Call `Verify` on the server certificates public key

This way you check the signature of the certificate. Which is the safest way. And also gives you the possibility to update the server certificate without updating the client. (As long as the CA is valid off course)

Source of Verify here: http://www.bouncycastle.org/viewcvs/viewcvs.cgi/csharp/crypto/src/x509/X509Certificate.cs?view=markup Line:540

Comment: So I would still need a proper CA certificate?

Comment: No any certificate that is signed by the certificate at the client side, that u use to verify the server certificate, will verify. So a self made CA will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, I don't think you can do this and trust that you have a secure channel.  Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but the CA trust chain in SSL isn't to just to verify that the thumbprint is a particular value (or some other part of the certificate). It proves that the the client is communicating with the *correct* server (due to a shared CA key). [This illustration](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tivihelp/v5r1/topic/com.ibm.itim.infocenter.doc/cpt/cpt_ic_security_ssl_authent.html) is a good reference. Skipping step 3, will not allow the server to prove its identity to the client (throw certificate validation).

`so that it will only ever trust my own server`

SSL guarantees this by using a shared CA certificate (like verisign etc).  Maybe I don't understand why you would *choose* not to just use SSL as it was intended.

**EDIT:**
As **the_ajp** points out in his answer, there are libraries (like bouncy castle) that will do a full verification on the certificate chain.  These can be called manually.

Comment: Step 4 "proving server identity" is afaik nothing more than comparing the comonname to the dnsname.

Comment: @the_ajp Yeah, sorry, got confused looking at that diagram.  I meant step 3. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Right thats the step I describe in my answer :)

Comment: @the_ajp Nice! missed that it verified the signature.  Very cool.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I just figure there should be a simpler way of verifying the server identity, without actually involving a CA. As long as the public key is matches, and the corresponding private key is known only by the server, it should be safe, right? This is the way SSH works.